# VBA Autofilter from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to the VBA. I am looking at getting few data from sheet1 with filtered data to move to sheet2. The criteria works for other filter data other than this one “<1st shift”
Please could you assist. 
I am using this code.

```
Sub copypaste() 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<1st Shift”
    Selection.Copy

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("B7").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: On Column I do you have any cell with the text "<1st Shift" or is it supposed to be "1st Shift"? Please could you provide a screenshot of how the data is displayed?

Comment: Thank you Xabier for looking into this. 
Yes the column has the text "<1st Shift". I'm afraid as I'm unable to attach the screenshot here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the following and it works for me, I've altered the code you are using to make sure that it only copies rows if they match the criteria.

Another thing to keep in mind is to steer away from using .Activate and .Select as these will only slow down your code, please have a look at the amended code below:

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim Rng As Range, LastRow As Long
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with, amend as required
ws1.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<1st Shift"
'filter Sheet1 Column H with criteria
Set Rng = ws1.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'set the range to be copied, only looking at the visible rows
LastRow = ws1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
'check the last row with data on Column B
If LastRow <> ws1.Rows.Count Then
'check if there are any rows that match the criteria
    Rng.Copy
    'copy the range
    ws2.Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    'paste into Sheet2 cell B7
Else
    MsgBox "Criteria not found", vbInformation, "Error"
End If
ws1.Cells.AutoFilter
'remove the AutoFilter
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

In the case where you have multiple criteria you can use the following code:

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim Rng As Range, LastRow As Long
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with, amend as required
ws1.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="5", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<1st Shift"
'filter Sheet1 Column H with criteria
Set Rng = ws1.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'set the range to be copied, only looking at the visible rows
LastRow = ws1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
'check the last row with data on Column B
If LastRow <> ws1.Rows.Count Then
'check if there are any rows that match the criteria
    Rng.Copy
    'copy the range
    ws2.Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    'paste into Sheet2 cell B7
Else
    MsgBox "Criteria not found", vbInformation, "Error"
End If
ws1.Cells.AutoFilter
'remove the AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this but when I run this code it says compile error : Variable not defined
This is highlighted when error Set Rng

Comment: @MohammedSufiyan I've now updated my answer to include the declaration for all variables, it should now work for you as intended. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Xabier. This code seems to be not working for this criteria "<1st Shift" but when I try all other conditions it works such as "13 weeks - 18 weeks"..... Do you think this lesser than sign "<" would be an issue.

Comment: @MohammedSufiyan I've tested this and I did not get a problem filtering for that specific Criteria, the "<" doesn't cause me any issues,... I'm unsure as to what to advise as I'm not encountering any issues with it.

Comment: I think i need one more help. Can you tell me how to add another criteria to this code pls

Comment: @MohammedSufiyan I've now updated my answer to illustrate how to go about filtering with multiple criteria, hope this helps. :)